# How to make a div appear outside a scroll container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, scroll

I have a table that is inside a div that allows horizontal and vertical scrolling. This table has a sticky header, and if you hover a cell, the corresponding row and column will highlight. When a cell is hovered, I also need a "popup" to cover the table head cell.

That is working, but because my container is scrollable, the "popup" gets cut instead of appearing outside it. The "popup" is just a div styled to appear over the cell. I made a fiddle here to show what I am doing:
https://jsfiddle.net/u4r7hvp8/1/

jquery:

```
//sticky header
$(".hm-table").each(function() {
  $(this).wrap("<div class='scrollable'></div>");
  $(this).clone().find("tbody").remove().end().insertBefore(this);
});


$("table").on('mouseover mouseleave', 'td', function(e) {
  if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
    //highlight row
    $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
    //highlight column
    $(this).closest('table').find("col").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");
    //expand column head cell
    $('.hm-table').find("tr:first").find(".target-1").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hidden");
    $('.hm-table').find("tr:first").find(".target-1").eq($(this).index()).addClass("title-1");
  } else {
    //remove row highlight
    $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
    //remove column highlight
    $(this).closest('table').find('col').eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");
    //remove column head expand
    $('.hm-table').find("tr:first").find(".target-1").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hidden");
    $('.hm-table').find("tr:first").find(".target-1").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("title-1");
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.scrollable {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.scrollable table:nth-child(1) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.scrollable table:nth-child(1) tbody {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.scrollable table:nth-child(2) thead {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.hover {
  background-color: #3a3f51;
}

.title-1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -31px;
  left: -22px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 80px !important;
  height: 67px !important;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  z-index: 1005;
}
```

Can anyone help me with getting this "popup" to fully appear over the table, and not be cut by the div?

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than it appears to be. However, there's [popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) to the rescue. In short, what it does is: instead of appending the popover to the parent element, it appends it to `<body>` and listens to any change in the actual position of the "parent", updating the position of the popover (or hiding it). Do note this is the only way to technically solve the problem, as absolutely ***nothing*** inside a scrollable div can be displayed outside of the scrollable div. That's how the scroll mechanism works.

Comment: Note that `popper.min.js` is one of the required Bootstrap v4 js scripts. See [Getting Started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I can't use that library. Also, I am using bootstrap 3, not 4. Would it be possible to replicate a bootstrap tooltip for this? When the tooltip is hovered, it appears as a separate div outside the container (at the bottom of the body).